# How to silence output from docker commands

Tags: docker, shell, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I have written a script to run some docker commands for me and I would like to silence the output from these commands. for example `docker load`, `docker run` or `docker stop`.

`docker load` does have a flag `--quiet` that seems like it should do what I want however when I try to use this it still prints out `Loaded image: myimage`. Even if this flag did work for me, not all docker commands have this flag available. I had tried to use redirection like `docker run ... 2>&1 /dev/null` however the redirection arguments are interpreted as commands arguments for the docker container and this seems to be the same for other docker commands as well, for example `tar -Oxf myimage.img.tgz | docker load 2>&1 /dev/null` assumes that the redirection are arguments and decides to print out the command usage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is mostly a shell question regarding standard descriptors (stdout, stderr) and redirections.

To achieve what you want, you should not write `cmd 2>&1 /dev/null` nor `cmd 2>&1 >/dev/null` but just write: **`cmd >/dev/null 2>&1`**

**Mnemonics:**

The intuition to easily think of this `>` syntax is:

- `>/dev/null` can be read: `STDOUT := /dev/null`
- `2>&1` can be read: `STDERR := STDOUT`

This way, the fact that `2>&1` must be placed **afterwards** becomes clear.

(As an aside, redirecting both stderr to stdout to a pipe is a bit different, and would be written in the following order: `cmd1 2>&1 | cmd2`)

**Minimal complete example to test this:**

```sh
$ cmd() { echo "stdout"; echo >&2 "stderr"; }

$ cmd 2>&1 >/dev/null  # does no work as intended
stderr

$ cmd >/dev/null 2>&1  # ok
```

Comment: how will this fare if you're running a `docker run` command? For example: `docker run -it node:lts-alpine /bin/sh`

Can you silence the output and still get inside the container as you'd expect from this command?